# Is there a way to organise video files by month in new directories?

Tags: python, bash, macos, terminal, file-management

I am relatively new to bash. I wanted to know if there was an existing command on Mac OS' terminal to seperate video files by month in new directories. Essentially, this means that if I have videos in a span of 12 months, I would have 12 new directories with the videos put inside.

Otherwise, I was wondering if there was another way I could do this maybe through python to solve such problem.

I was hoping to use this to work with 500+ video files. It would tremendously help me if I could just have a script doing it for me instead of going through them one by one.

**Before Script**

[image]

[image]

**After Script(Desired Output)**

[image]

**Update (found the solution)**

I ended up finding the solution thank you for leading me to the right answer. Now I learnt one new thing today

```
import os, shutil 
from datetime import datetime

filepath = "/Users/alfietorres/Downloads/"      #base file path 
for filename in os.listdir(filepath):           #iterate through each file in the directory

    r = os.stat(filepath+filename)              #look for the file path and the file name
    d = r.st_birthtime                          #look for the time created 
    date=datetime.fromtimestamp(d)              #assign the details to a date variable

    month_directory = filepath+str(date.month)+"-"+str(date.year)      #use the date variable to create a UNIQUE new directory 
    file_being_moved = filepath+filename        #file the path of the file being moved    

    if os.path.isdir(month_directory) :         #check if the directory is created
        print("directory found ... ")
        shutil.move(file_being_moved,month_directory)   #move the file we are iterating on to the directory
    else: 
        print("creating directory ... ")        
        os.mkdir(month_directory)                       #create new directory 
        shutil.move(file_being_moved,month_directory)   #move items in new directory
```

Comment: Yes, this is pretty straight forward. How do you know which video belongs to which month? Is it in the filename? Metadata? Modified time?

Comment: Sorry, I checked it again. I fixed the OP again. I found that there was a way to seperate the files by **date created**. Still is there a way to just to this automatically?

Comment: Is the creation date the same as you get from `GetFileInfo -d yourfile.mov`?

Comment: Yes it is  Input: GetFileInfo -d IMG_2997\ 2.HEIC Output: 02/15/2020 17:36:59. Which is the same as the get file info GUI

Comment: So you're interested in the `.MOV` or `.mov` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a python script that does it for you.

Use `os` module to get information about your files. Especially creation time:

```
import os
r = os.stat("path/to/file")
print(r.st_ctime_ns)   # it prints the number of nano seconds since creation (Windows OS)
```

In order to get the list of files/directories in a directory, you can use `os` module too:

```
os.listdir("path/to/directory/")  # you get a list of all files/directories
```

In order to convert the timestamp into a datetime, you can use `datetime` module:

```
from datetime import datetime
d = r.st_ctime_ns // 1000000   # convert to seconds
date = datetime.fromtimestamp(d)
print(date)   ##  datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 19, 5, 37, 22)
print(date.year)  ## get the year
print(date.month)  ## get the month
print(date.day)   ## get the day
```

Now you have just to compbine these information to organize your files.

## Other useful information:

- To create a directory, use `os.mkdir("directory name")`
- To move a file, use `os.rename("old path", "new path")`

Answer (score 0):

> seperate video files by month in new directories

From `info date`

```
‘-r FILE’
‘--reference=FILE’
     Display the date and time of the last modification of FILE, instead
     of the current date and time.
```

So to get the month from the last modification time of the file.

```
date -r file '+%m'
```

---

With `bash` and `find`.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dirs=("$@")

find "${dirs[@]}" -type f -print0 | {
  while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
    file_name=${file##*/}
    path_name=${file%"$file_name"}
    directory=$(date -r "$file" "+%m")
    if ! [[ -e "${path_name}month$directory" && -d "${path_name}month$directory" ]]; then
      echo mkdir -p "${path_name}month$directory" && echo mv -v "$file" "${path_name}month$directory"
    else
      echo mv -v "$file" "${path_name}month$directory"
    fi
  done
}
```

---

To use the script, assuming the name of the script is `myscript` and `folder_name` is the name of the directory in question.

```
./myscript folder_name
```

Or with multiple folders/directories

```
./myscript folder1 folder2 folder3 folder4 another_folder /path/to/folder
```

- The `-type f` looks for files and not directories.
- Remove all the `echo` if you're satisfied with the output, and change all `mv` to `cp` just to copy files and not move them completely.